# Dynamic column value in Blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to move one collection's single column value to another new collection(let's say collectionB), for doing this I am using calc stage where data is passed one after the another.

In the calc stage I have added the  and move it  but here in CollectionA.columnname1, columnname1 is dynamic, it's value is a today's date (6/20), I tried concatenation to create CollectionA.6/20 but it's taking it as a string and passing the same value to the collectionB instead of taking the 6/20 column name of the collection A.

Answer (score 1):

To get that done you will need to develop an action in Utility - collection Manipulation.

Please see example code below:

```
If RowIndex < 0 OrElse Coll.Rows.Count <= RowIndex Then
    Throw New ApplicationException("The supplied row index falls outside of the valid range.")
End If

If Not Coll.Columns.Contains(FieldName) Then
   Throw New ApplicationException("The collection does not contain a field with the name '" & FieldName & "'")
End If

Coll.Rows(RowIndex)(FieldName) = New_Value

Updated_Collection = Coll
```

There are 5 variables used in that stage:

- Coll - an input collection
- RowIndex - the row number into which you want to input variable. First row has number 0.
- FieldName - column name into which you want to input variable
- New Value - the value that you want to put into collection
- Updated_Collection - output collection

Please see image refence:[image]

Using that action you can pass a field name to object from variable.

Comment: Here what will be my RowIndex,FieldName and New_Value in   Coll.Rows(RowIndex)(FieldName) = New_Value

Comment: I've added variables description above